# Font awesome icon not visible

Tags: html, css

I am using Font awesome cdn in my header

but still icons are not visible

```html
<div class ="star-rating-container">
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: cdn ----->  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/50a7448982.js"></script> //in header

Comment: Please add more details about what stylesheets and scripts from Font Awesome you are implementing and how.

Comment: Please also put the code in your post itself (click [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68349180/edit)) and not in comments.

Comment: What lib are you loading, show the html where the scripts are linked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot `https://` in your link. Also, `fas` didn't work for me, so I put `fa` Here is a fiddle that works:

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/50a7448982.js"></script>

<div class ="star-rating-container">
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: fas is correct: https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/star?style=solid (fa is not more available in the V5)